# How to redirect user to webpage after entering the right code?

Tags: php, html, forms

There's a concert on my school, which I will be live streaming. Instead of going to a link like youtu.be/83djae, I want people to go to something simple where they will have to enter a password. If they enter the right password, then they will be redirected to YouTube, if the password is wrong, then they will be asked to write it again. 
This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<form>
<p>Password:</p>
<input type="text" name="password">
</form>
</html>
```

It doesn't have to be pretty or something, just redirect.
Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: As you tagged `php` and not `javascript`, it should be like this. `<?php header('Location: otherfile.php'); ?>`

Comment: sounds like homework; what have you researched/tried before signing up on Stack?

Comment: @NeerajKumar that question was closed as as not a real question

Comment: Please include some PHP code that you tried so far, so we can help you debug or improve it.

Comment: What if one person writes the correct password and then shares the direct youtube link with everyone else?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Location: location.php'); ?>
```